# How to click the button using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm new to  Python and Selenium and I want to click the button "Afficher plus" in [this url](https://www.seloger.com/professionnels/agences-immobilieres/paris-15eme-75/agency-61886.htm#?bd=Detail_Agenceb_ann).

i've tried this code :

```
plus = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='b-btn b- 
ghost']")
plus.click()
```

but it doesn't work and i get this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (390, 581). Other element would receive the click: ...

Comment: It does mean exactly what is given in the error message: whichever element is selected by that query is not clickable

Comment: it means i have to make a time sleep to load the page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element you are trying to click is not clickable, or might be overlapped.

Try to click specified element, by executing java script click function.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

On another hand, your page might not yet be fully loaded, so element might not be clickable yet, you can use wait for condition:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable(By...)) //change selector

element.click();
```

Comment: i've tried the second solution but it didn't work i get the same problem

Comment: Try to combine 1st and 2nd option, replace last line of the second option with line from the first option (click using JS)

Comment: i did and i get this error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

Comment: it's okay now it was a problem of the webdriver version

Answer (score 0):

To click the button with text as **Afficher plus de biens** within this [url](https://www.seloger.com/professionnels/agences-immobilieres/paris-15eme-75/agency-61886.htm#?bd=Detail_Agenceb_ann) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.b-btn.b-ghost"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='b-btn b-ghost' and contains(., 'Afficher plus')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```